# Is the TypeScript type system too relaxed in this case?

Tags: typescript, type-systems, structural-typing

I think I've encountered a scenario that seems like it should cause the TS compiler to error (but it isn't) and I'm hoping someone can explain why.

In the code below I'm passing an interface `Foo` to the function `frobnicator` which it accepts. Then, in the body of `frobnicator`, I "remove" the field `bar.y`. After `frobnicator` terminates, the type system allows me to print `bar.y` (without error'ing) despite `y` no longer existing.

Shouldn't the type system forbid me from passing `foo` to `frobnicator` because now `foo` doesn't implement the `Foo` interface anymore and TS thinks it does?

```
interface Foo {
    bar: { x: number, y: number };
}

function frobnicator(thing: { bar: { x: number } }) {
    thing.bar = { x: 1 }; // "remove" bar.y
}

const foo: Foo = { bar: { x: 1, y: 2 } };
frobnicator(foo); // The implementation "removes" bar.y
console.log(foo.bar.y); // TypeScript does not error despite bar.y missing
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer is yes, your code demonstrates an unsound behaviour of Typescript's type system, for exactly the reason you described in your question.

The answer is also no, you didn't "break" Typescript's type system, because this unsound behaviour is the intended behaviour. Typescript is not totally sound, and is not meant to be totally sound; quoting from [the docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/type-compatibility.html#a-note-on-soundness):

> TypeScript’s type system allows certain operations that can’t be known at compile-time to be safe. When a type system has this property, it is said to not be “sound”. The places where TypeScript allows unsound behavior were carefully considered, and throughout this document we’ll explain where these happen and the motivating scenarios behind them.

Typescript's designers explicitly  chose a balance between soundness and usefulness; a fully sound type system would not treat `{bar: {x: number, y: number}}` as a subtype of `{bar: {x: number}}`, but real Javascript code typically does pass around objects with more properties than the function will actually access, so the strictly sound behaviour would not be very useful to developers who write realistic Javascript code.

Answer (score 2):

Your interface has nothing to do with your code inside the function as even though the type of your const is Foo, the function accepts not foo, but the unnamed type `{ bar: { x: number } }`. As Typescript is working in *compile time* and not in the *runtime* it cannot possibly know that your function removed `y` as the type inside the function does not have `y` and the type outside it is `Foo` which is a supertype of the function argument type and so its instances fit into the type of the argument. So, on one hand your function removes a field from the object, but you don't tell the compiler that it's forbidden as the type inside the function is different from the type you pass in it, so outside it still thinks that you have `y`. It seems counterintuitive after languages like Java but that's just how it is.  To avoid such issues you should use proper typing, like, for instance, using your interface type inside the function.

Comment: This "As Typescript is working in _compile time_ and _not in the runtime_" is one of the most important things to understand about TypeScript.

Comment: My issue is the TS compiler seems too relaxed in this case. It could easily reject `foo` since it isn't structurally equivalent to the unnamed type.

Comment: @hgs3 it will reject `Foo` if it does not have they keys you listed in the function argument type, but as far as it has all required keys, it's OK. It would be clumsy otherwise as it would not allow for polymorphism.

Comment: Couldn't you still be polymorphic on the top-level keys? For example, imagine if `Foo` had another field `baz`: In this scenario, it would still be both safe and polymorphic for `frobnicator` to accept a `Foo` since all it expects is a `bar` and it could retain full safety by ensuring `bar` is structurally equivalent. If this is just how TS works, that's fine, but I do think it could achieve polymorphism even with a stricter/safer type system.

Answer (score 0):

The function just expects a nested dictionary.
Not the exact amount of keys.

Comment: I get that, but from the call site TypeScript still things `foo` implements the `Foo` interface. I can print `foo.bar.y` without any errors because TS thinks it's present. TS _will_ error if I print a field not present on `Foo`, like `foo.bar.z`.